# Javascript Radio Button Checked needs to be clicked to be active

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the below code to switch between a select and a text box in a form, however despite the select being checked I still need to actually click the radio button otherwise it just sends blank information.

```
<input onclick="document.getElementById('codemenu').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('codecustom').disabled = true;" type="radio"
name="codebutton" value=""  checked="checked">

   <select name="exp_code" id="codemenu">
    <option value="MATS">MATS</option>
    <option value="WAGES">WAGES</option>
    <option value="FUEL">FUEL</option>
    <option value="AD">AD</option>
    <option value="TAX">TAX</option>
    <option value="GAS">GAS</option>
    <option value="OH">OH</option>
    </select>
 <p>
<input onclick="document.getElementById('codecustom').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('codemenu').disabled = true;" type="radio"
name="codebutton">

<input type="text" name="exp_code" id="codecustom" placeholder="Custom Code" 
autocomplete="on">
```

Sourced from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491297/input-field-disabled-until-radio-button-is-checked-html)

I have a feeling I need to add some scripting in the header such as the following but I don't use javascript that often.

```
<head>
      <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementByID.exp_form.type[0].checked = true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `it just sends blank information`...when you submit the form?  I don't actually see a `<form>`

Comment: This is just a section of the middle of the form.

Comment: Your radio inputs need values, then you should see something being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an id to your checkbox and the perform a click when loading the view.

Try this :

```html
<input onclick="document.getElementById('codemenu').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('codecustom').disabled = true;" type="radio"
name="codebutton" value=""  checked="checked" id="exp_form">

   <select name="exp_code" id="codemenu">
    <option value="MATS">MATS</option>
    <option value="WAGES">WAGES</option>
    <option value="FUEL">FUEL</option>
    <option value="AD">AD</option>
    <option value="TAX">TAX</option>
    <option value="GAS">GAS</option>
    <option value="OH">OH</option>
    </select>
 <p>
<input onclick="document.getElementById('codecustom').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('codemenu').disabled = true;" type="radio"
name="codebutton">

<input type="text" name="exp_code" id="codecustom" placeholder="Custom Code" 
autocomplete="on">

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('exp_form');
    if (el.onclick) {
       el.onclick();
    } else if (el.click) {
       el.click();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: OK that works.  Now I have a second part of my form that runs in the same way, but implementing another script with id, variables and function names changed to suit is still conflicting.

Comment: Sorry, I've got it working.  Just to clarify I ran both if statements inside the same function.  Given that I'm not that up on Javascript would you mind describing what is happening in your script so that I can learn for future.  I recognise that you call a function and that you define a variable for the element ID, it's the if statement that is confusing me somewhat as I'm used to php if statements.

Comment: the if statement is just for checking which function to exists if it exists. if `onclick` function exists if will be executed else where when check for the `click` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input onclick="document.getElementById('codemenu').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('codecustom').disabled = true;" type="radio"
name="codebutton" value=""  checked="checked">

<select name="exp_code" id="codemenu">
<option value="MATS">MATS</option>
<option value="WAGES">WAGES</option>
<option value="FUEL">FUEL</option>
<option value="AD">AD</option>
<option value="TAX">TAX</option>
<option value="GAS">GAS</option>
<option value="OH">OH</option>
</select>
<p>
<input onclick="document.getElementById('codecustom').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('codemenu').disabled = true;" type="radio"
name="codebutton">

<input type="text" name="exp_code" id="codecustom" placeholder="Custom Code" 
disabled="disabled"
autocomplete="on">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to select the first option in HTML:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Basic_select

```
<option value="MATS" selected>MATS</option>
```